# Hyperlinking of text in facebook with Social Framework

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, ios5, ios6

I was trying to hyperlink only specific part of string to a url with the below code on Facebook

```
SLComposeViewController *fbController=[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
NSString *strURL =@"http://ec2-54-215-150-229.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/TripScope/printguide/25157";
NSString *strHtml=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<a href=%@>Booked by me</a> \n TripAgency",strURL];
[fbController setInitialText:strHtml];
```

With the above code, it was showing the html text on facebook.

How can i fix this? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot post HTML to Facebook.

You might be able to pull in metadata from your URL using [Open Graph tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/).